# How to configure Trusted_Host_Settings for subdomains?

Tags: configuration

How to configure Trusted_Host_Settings for subdomains?

The documentation does not give an example of a subdomain.

For example, I have an Add-On domain that points to website.info, but the subdomain is mainsite.com/website.info

Comment: Did not work. Invalid hostname for this computer.

Perhaps using the term subdomain caused confusion.

The pattern I have to match is:

domain.com/subdomain.info

Sites in folders under the main domain.

Answer (score 6):

It's actually documented in `settings.php` file as in examples:

Drupal 8.5.x
https://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/sites/default/default.settings.php?h=8.5.x#n712

```
<?php
$settings['trusted_host_patterns'] = [
  '^example\.com$',           // Matches naked domain only.
  '^.+\.example\.com$',       // Matches any subdomains.
  '^subdomain\.example\.com', // Matches a specific subdomain.
];
```

You can easily define any naked or sub-domain, as long as defined regex pattern matches them correctly.

Comment: Good catch The other things I have seen did not provide a pattern like this. Thanks.

Comment: Did not work.

domain.com/subdomain.info

Matching the folder structure of sites under the main site.

Comment: You really should read the documentation for the `trusted_host_patterns`  setting. As the name suggests, it's for setting up trusted hostnames. If you don't know the difference between host and path, I also recommend reading up [What is a URL?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL) at MDN.

Comment: I found when using trusted_host_patterns in a development area with a deeper structure, I needed to add multiple lines like so: $settings['trusted_host_patterns'] = array(
      '^example\.com$',
      '^work\.example\.com$',
      '^dev\.work\.example\.com$',
   );